# properly escaping special characters in the relation TYPE?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a relation `type` named `str-dist`
The hyphen is making cypher very unhappy. What is the correct way to handle the hyphen?  (We ultimately resolved this by renaming the relationsip type, but I remain curious for learnings' sake)

```
// Intended Query: 
MATCH n:Cars-[:str-dist]-m:Cars
RETURN n, m

// Tried all of the following, with no luck
MATCH n:Cars-[:str`-dist]-m:Cars
MATCH n:Cars-[:str\-dist]-m:Cars
MATCH n:Cars-[:"str-dist"]-m:Cars
MATCH n:Cars-[:'str-dist']-m:Cars
MATCH n:Cars-[:`str-dist`]-m:Cars
```

Answer (score 4):

The [Neo4j manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-expressions.html) uses backticks to escape special characters in an identifier or relationship type:

```
MATCH n:Cars-[:`str-dist`]-m:Cars
```

Comment: hmm... thats interesting.  I wonder if the fact that it was created through cypher or with the backticks already present is impacting this?